# Transforming Matrix to matrix of zero; custom transformation rules

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, math, matrix

You are given an `8x8` table of **natural numbers**. (Consider the Magic Matrix, lets say). In any one step, you can either *`double each of the numbers in any row`*, or *`subtract 1 from each of the numbers in any one column`*. Devise
an algorithm that *`transforms the original table into a table of all zeros`*.

I tried using the algorithm described below, but it just takes really really long. The no of operations even for a 3x3 matrix is of the order of 10^49. 
Can anyone using this algorithm, computer what will be the time complexity of the algorithm for 8x8 matrix?
I'm quoting my code below; does anyone have a better efficiency algorithm,

```
dim = 3;
m=magic(dim)
for i=1:dim
    c=0;
    while(length(find(m(:,i)==2))~=length(m(:,i)))
        c = c + 1;
        if length(find(m(:,i)==1))>0
            for j=find(m(:,i)==1)
                m(j,:)=m(j,:)*2;

            end
        end
%         m
        if (i==2)
        m
        end

        if (length(find(m(:,i)==2))~=length(m(:,i)))
            k = min(m(find(m(:,i)>=2),i));
            l = length(find(m(:,i)==2));
            m(:,i)=m(:,i)-(k-1);
        end
%         m
        if (i==2)
       m
        end
%           if(i==3 && mod(c,100)==0)
%               c
%           end
    end
    i
    m(:,i)=m(:,i)-2
end
m
```

Comment: What is the brute-force way you tried?

Comment: It might be you did not get it because this problem is not solvable for any input, for example `M=ones(8,8);M(1)=2;`. Maybe start writing a problem generator which generates solvable instances. Start with a zero matrix and imply inverted steps, then you get a solvable matrix and you know the solution.

Comment: @Daniel your example is wrong Prateek mentioned natural number which is start from 1. And this problem always have answer, just look at my algorithm below :)

Comment: Bear in mind that these algorithms will likely be prone to integer overflow.

Comment: I updated my example, the original was [1,0;0,1].

Comment: @Daniel: `M=ones(8,8);M(1)=2;` will be solveable: Multiply all but the first row by two, do twice subtraction from column 1, multiply first row by 2, do twice subtraction form all but column 1.

Comment: @knedlsepp yes you are right, as I said this algorithm 100% could be improved, I'll be glad if you suggest improvement or better algorithm :)

Comment: @moderators This question didnot seems to be off-topic, I really think it is nice question, and I'm waiting to someone post a better answer than mine, so it would be nice if you reopen this question :)

Answer (score 1):

There one solution like below but it could be improved I think :

1. dont consider other column and in every step just focus on one column.
2. with below steps convert this column to zeros with trying to changing every item in this column to 2:

   - consider lowest non zero not 2 item in the column is `m`.
   - subtract this column `m-1` times.
   - in above step in any item of row became 1 multiple its column with 2.
   - repeat this three steps until you have all 2 column.
3. now subtract the column from step 2, two times with 1.
4. repeat step 1 to 3 for all 8 columns.

if the maximum of your table is M this algorithm order is O(M). Because table have constant 64 items.

I hope my algorithm is clear, but if there is any thing you dont understand, please ask.

**Edit:** for understanding this better I just do this steps for a simple matrix that you find [here](http://pastebin.com/9q4jrmWN).

Comment: Do you mean, in step 2(iii), that 
'in above step in any item of column became 1 multiply its row with 2' ?
I'm not clear with step2(iii) and (iv)

Comment: @Prateek see this link http://pastebin.com/9q4jrmWN and this will solve your problem :)

Comment: @Prateek did you see my edit? are you still have any question?

Comment: Yes I did see the edit. I checked this works, but it just becomes really really big! My pc, cannot even complete it even for a 3x3 magic matrix. The number, while zeroing the first two columns itself, become in the order of 10^48. It just then does not finish at all.
Can you tell me what do you mean by that statement that the order of the algorithm is O(M) ?

Comment: @Prateek really? That big? I though it would be big, but not that much! Are you getting an overflow? Or time complexity is your problem?

Comment: I don't understand the these terms, overflow, or time-complexity, I'm really sorry. I can put down my code, though.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/fX8B5KuabqWLJpJQjexruP
This doesn't finish in even in a very very long time.

Comment: @Prateek please dont edit your old comment, leave a new comment, when you do that I didnt see what you said because there is no notification for that, as I said I dont understand matlab that good, I think maybe it is your code's proble:)

Comment: That's alright. And I thank you a lot :) Can you tell me what is the time-complexity of this particular algorithm. I have to report an algorithm and its time-complexity somewhere. Or can you tell me how can I find it ?

Comment: @Prateek before you say that your code would stop even for n =3 I though my Time complexity is O(M) where M is be biggest number in your matrix, but now I think maybe I'm wrong, right now I cant think straight but I'll inform you in Saturday if I find anything more than that.